# Guards vs funções com pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Estou começando em Haskell e estava fazendo uns exercícios dela no [Exercism](http://exercism.io).
Ao enviar um código, fui comparar com os dos outros e me deparei com um bem parecido ao meu, mas usava uma definição de *guards* (não sei se chega a ser *guard*, vi em um lugar chamando de função por *pattern matching*, mas sem certeza) diferente:

```
-- Minha função
transcribe :: Char -> Maybe Char
transcribe nucleotide
    | nucleotide == 'G' = Just 'C'
    | nucleotide == 'C' = Just 'G'
    | nucleotide == 'T' = Just 'A'
    | nucleotide == 'A' = Just 'U'
    | otherwise         = Nothing

-- Função de outro participante
transcribe :: Char -> Maybe Char
transcribe 'G' = Just 'C'
transcribe 'C' = Just 'G'
transcribe 'T' = Just 'A'
transcribe 'A' = Just 'U'
transcribe _   = Nothing
```

Então gostaria de entender, existe alguma diferença entre as duas formas? Para casos como esse, qual é a mais correta? Ou as duas no fim são a mesma coisa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiramente, a sua função é que usa **guardas** (*guards*), enquanto que a do outro participante usa **casamento de padrões** (*patter matching*). Além disso, ambas terão sempre os mesmos resultados e são semanticamente iguais.

Escolher escrever de um jeito ou de outro é questão de estilo ou para facilitar a leitura. Neste caso, como a comparação de cada guarda é apenas igualdade em todos os casos (`nucleotide == ...`), o mais comum é optar por casamento de padrões, mesmo sabendo que não faz diferença.

Talvez você queira ler um pouco sobre casamento de padrões:

- [Wikilivro (pt)](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Casamento_de_padr%C3%B5es).
- [LYaHfGG (pt)](http://haskell.tailorfontela.com.br/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching).